# Loop through multiple Excel files and write data from each file to a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop through multiple excel files in a folder, write to a new data frame, then filter by column name. It should only show the property address in the first column, then 3 other columns with corresponding dollar values below the headers. The issue is that each file may not have the same columns or they're duplicate. Here's my code:

```
read_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/watso/Desktop/yardi_testing_desktop/yardi_downloads/*.xlsx')
files_xlsx = [f for f in read_files if f[-4:] == "xlsx"]

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xlsx:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.transpose()
    new_header = df.iloc[0]  # grab the first row for the header
    df = df[1:]  # take the data less the header row
    df.columns = new_header  # set the header row as the df header
    df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.strip()
    df = df.iloc[:2, 3:]
    all_data = all_data.append(df, sort=True)
    all_data.to_csv('C:/Users/watso/PycharmProjects/yardi_noi/yyy.csv', index=False, header=0)
```

Here's the data frame it creates:

```
----------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                                           |        | ASSETS |  | RENTAL REVENUES |  | RENTAL INCOME               | Rental Inc:  Base Rent | Rental Inc:  Telecom Transmit | Total Rental Revenue |                            | TENANT FUNDED IMPROVEMENTS | Tenant Funded Improvements       | Total Tenant Funded Improvements |                         | STRAIGHT LINE RENT | Straight Line Rent       |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 64 Fake Street - Stony Village(6546-01)   | Actual |        |  |                 |  |                             | 208598.27              | 2519.7                        | 211117.97            |                            |                            | 4963.73                          | 4963.73                          |                         |                    | -18726.86                |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                                           |        | ASSETS |  | RENTAL REVENUES |  | PROPERTY OPERATING EXPENSES |                        | REIMBURSABLE EXPENSES         |                      | OTHER (INCOME) / EXPENSE   |                            | OTHER (INCOME)                   |                                  |                         |                    |                          |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 234 Fake Street - Santa Wilshire(6668-01) | Actual |        |  |                 |  |                             |                        |                               |                      |                            |                            |                                  |                                  |                         |                    |                          |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                                           |        | ASSETS |  | RENTAL REVENUES |  | RENTAL INCOME               | Rental Inc:  Base Rent | Rental Inc:  Incidental       | Total Rental Revenue |                            | Total Rental Revenues      |                                  | OTHER INCOME                     | Oth Inc:  Miscellaneous | Total Other Income |                          |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 255 Fake Street - Minneapolis(9879-02)    | Actual |        |  |                 |  |                             | -12490.27              | -1060                         | -13550.27            |                            | -13550.27                  |                                  |                                  | 100                     | 100                |                          |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                                           |        | ASSETS |  | RENTAL REVENUES |  | RENTAL INCOME               | Rental Inc:  Base Rent | Total Rental Revenue          |                      | TENANT FUNDED IMPROVEMENTS | Tenant Funded Improvements | Total Tenant Funded Improvements |                                  | STRAIGHT LINE RENT      | Straight Line Rent | Total Straight-Line Rent |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 543 Fake Street - Seattle(6684-01)        | Actual |        |  |                 |  |                             | 339802.38              | 339802.38                     |                      |                            | 39841.64                   | 39841.64                         |                                  |                         | 1645.96            | 1645.96                  |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+--+-----------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

The problem is when I try to select columns by loc() but get an error stating that the columns I choose aren't in the index. Here is how I want the table to look:

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
|                                           | Rental Inc:  Base Rent | Total Rental Revenue | Tenant Funded Improvements |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| 64 Fake Street - Stony Village(6546-01)   | 208598.27              | 211117.97            | 4963.73                    |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| 234 Fake Street - Santa Wilshire(6668-01) | Nan                    | Nan                  | Nan                        |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| 255 Fake Street - Minneapolis(9879-02)    | -12490.27              | -13550.27            | Nan                        |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| 543 Fake Street - Seattle(6684-01)        | 339802.38              | Nan                  | 39841.64                   |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

I've been trying to figure this out for almost two weeks before I'm asking for help here. Let me know if you need more info. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to help without knowing how the excel file looks like and the exact output you're getting. What are Actual, ASSETS and RENTAL REVENUES? Are they values or is the code reading strings?
Which input did you use with .loc[]?

Move the .to_csv command out of the loop, unless you really planned to save a csv during each loop.

Comment: Hello, welcome :)) Please [read this post on how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and refer to this one on [how to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question accordingly so people in the community can easily help you.